# Status Aborted when making http requests with DELETE method

Tags: ajax, yii2

I've been trying to set up an image uploader using Blueimp jQuery File Upload plugin. Everything works fine in my local development environment, but when I deploy my app to a shared hosting environment (000webhost), the ajax requests via DELETE method don't work. I can upload images, but cannot delete them.

I can't find the reason why this is happening. Firebug says that the request is in Aborted status, and I get no response from the server.

I'm using Yii 2.0.12 advanced application template.

What might the issue be? Maybe a problem with the request headers?

This is a screenshot with the info that Firebug provides:

This is my error:

[image]

Comment: can you add your controller code?

Comment: controller code with behaviours and particular action

Comment: havent tried this but from docs i can guess you may want to try getIsDelete() method and then put your logic of processing.. as it is like
Yii::$app->request->get() / Yii::$app->request->post()  you dont get delete()